# CUDA C library in Python. Transfer gpu memory data from one functions to ower

Tags: python, cuda

In python, I would like to write an algorithm using functions written in CUDA.
And I'm trying to avoid copying data from device to host to transfer data from the dll function to python, and then to another dll function.

Here is some sample code how I am trying to do it:

First function create array in gpu memory. Second - receives this array, and copies to host memory.

CUDA c:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void HostToDevice(void *Device_data, int len)
{
    int  err;

    float *host_data = (float*)malloc(len*sizeof(float));
    float k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<len; i+=1) { host_data[i] = k; k+=1;}
    cudaMalloc((void**)&Device_data, len*sizeof(float));

    err = cudaMemcpy(Device_data, host_data, len*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    printf("array addres %p\n", Device_data);
    printf("MemcpyHostToDevice error %d\n",err);
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void DeviceToHost(void *Device_data, void *Host_data, int len)
{
    int  err;

    err = cudaMemcpy(Host_data, Device_data, len*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    printf("array addres %p\n", Device_data);
    printf("MemcpyDeviceToHost error %d\n",err);

}
```

Python:

```
HostToDevice = Synth_dll.HostToDevice
DeviceToHost = Synth_dll.DeviceToHost
HostToDevice.argtypes = [c_void_p, c_size_t]
DeviceToHost.argtypes = [c_void_p, c_void_p, c_size_t]

host = np.empty((len)).astype(np.float32)
Device = np.empty((len)).astype(np.float32)


HostToDevice(c_void_p(Device.ctypes.data), len)
DeviceToHost(c_void_p(Device.ctypes.data), c_void_p(host.ctypes.data), len)
```

But this not worked. cudaMemcpy returns an error.

output:

```
array addres 0000000B22A40600
MemcpyHostToDevice error 0
array addres 0000019BD96577C0
MemcpyDeviceToHost error 1
```

Comment: Your HostToDevice function is totally broken. You can't modify an argument passed by value in C like that. PyCUDA already has all of this implemented. Why don't you use that instead of reinventing a (broken) wheel?

Comment: I ask the question, what is the mistake. I am not posting the code to criticize it.
The HostToDevice function works, except that I don't understand how to pass a pointer to data in the GPU memory. I use pyCuda, but i also need calculate FFT, with different configurations. Because of this, the compilation time of these various is quite long using reikna, for example. Use CUDA, I am using an already compiled dll, which saves me time.

Comment: There isn't one mistake, there are many. The whole idea of the `HostToDevice` is wrong. As is declaring `Device` as an array. Here is a hint: write the C code and test it with C code before trying to interface it to Python code and discovering something is broken. This is never going to work if the C code itself is wrong. And PyCUDA has an implementation. Even if you don't use the library -- go and look at the code. You will learn a lot

Answer (score 1):

I found solution:

CUDA:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void HostToDevice(float **Device_data, int len)
{
    int  err;

    float *host_data = (float*)malloc(len*sizeof(float));
    float k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<len; i+=1) { host_data[i] = k; k+=1;}

    float *Data;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&Data, len*sizeof(float));
    err = cudaMemcpy(Data, host_data, len*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    *Device_data = Data;

    printf("array addres %p\n", Device_data);
    printf("MemcpyHostToDevice error %d\n",err);
}


extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void DeviceToHost(float **Device_data, int len)
{
    int  err;
    float *Host_data = (float*)malloc(len*sizeof(float));


    err = cudaMemcpy(Host_data, *Device_data, len*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    printf("array addres %p\n", Device_data);
    for(int i=0; i<len; i+=1){printf("data %f\n", Host_data[i]);}
    printf("MemcpyDeviceToHost error %d\n",err);

}
```

Python:

```
HostToDevice = Synth_dll.HostToDevice
DeviceToHost = Synth_dll.DeviceToHost
HostToDevice.argtypes = [POINTER(POINTER(c_float)), c_size_t]
DeviceToHost.argtypes = [POINTER(POINTER(c_float)), c_size_t]


Device = POINTER(c_float)()

HostToDevice((Device), 4)
DeviceToHost((Device), 4)
```

output:

```
array addres 00000276755E1F90
MemcpyHostToDevice error 0


array addres 00000276755E1F90
data 0.000000
data 1.000000
data 2.000000
data 3.000000
MemcpyDeviceToHost error 0
```